# STM32 Cube IDE Execute Command in Linux

Tags: stm32, ros, wsl-2, ros2, stm32cubeide

I have installed STM32 Cube IDE in wsl.

So I'm trying to run it as a command in the terminal, but I don't know how to do it.

I need some help.

I connected to wsl with a virtual desktop screen and ran stm32cubeide, but it works without any problems.

However, I don't know about running it in terminal.

Comment: Just wanted to know why you want to do this? CubeIDE works in windows

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the file path correctly.

/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.13.1/stm32cubeide

Just go to the path and run stm32cubeide.